# My function keeps on adding product in the cart even if it exists and does not show any alert. How do I avoid this issue?

Tags: javascript, php

My function keeps on adding product in the cart even if it exists  and does not show any alert. How do I avoid this issue?

```
function cart(){       
               if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
                require('inc/connect.php');
        
                $ip = getIp();
                $product_id = filter_var($_POST['productId'],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
                $quatity    = filter_var($_POST['quantity'],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
                $size       = filter_var($_POST['size'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                
                $a = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE productid = '$product_id' AND ipAddress='$ip' ";
                $result = $con->prepare($a);
                $checkcart = $result->execute();
                
                if($checkcart == 1){
        
                    echo"<script>alert('Product Added Already</script>";
                    echo"<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
                }else{
                     $case = "INSERT INTO cart(productid,quantity,size,ipAddress)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
                    $stmt = $con->prepare($case);     
                    $check = $stmt->execute(array($product_id,$quatity,$size,$ip));
        
                    if(!$check){
        
                        echo"<script>alert('Sorry, Product not added please try Again !)</script>";
                        echo"<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
        
                    }else{
                        echo"<script>alert('Product Added to cart</script>";
                        echo"<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
                    }
                }
                         
                }    
               
           }
```

Comment: missing closing bracket in echo"<script>alert('Product Added Already</script>"; should be echo"<script>alert('Product Added Already');</script>"; and $checkcart == 1 shouldnt that be count($checkcart) >= 1) ? same in echo"<script>alert('Product Added to cart</script>"; and missing quote in  echo"<script>alert('Sorry, Product not added please try Again !)</script>";

Comment: OT: You should not use the IP address as (sole) crtierion to try and identify a specific user. Multiple people can easily “share” the same IP address from an outside perspective, keyword NAT.

Comment: `if($checkcart == 1)` – the return value of the `execute` method has nothing to do with the number of returned records, it only indicates whether the query was successful or not. (A query that simple does not return any records, because the WHERE criteria did not match, is still _successful_.)

Comment: @ FatFreddy, Thanks for the advice it worked .

Comment: @cBroe , What should the right query be ... Thanks in advance .

Comment: $checkcart = $result->fetchAll(); after the execute, then $checkcart is filled up as an array with the records, then do a count($checkcart) for calculating amount of records selected